# Database computed property that is a foreign key in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, computed-properties

How can I reference a property to be a ForeignKey plugged to a DB computed field (from a view) ?

I have the following :

```
public class PersonSite
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    //...

    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}

    //...

}

public class Person
{
      public Id {get;set;}

      //...

      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
      public int? MainPersonSiteId { get; protected internal set; }

      [ForeignKey("MainPersonSiteId")]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
      public PersonSite MainPersonSite { get; protected internal set; }

      //...
}
```

Whenever I try to update a `Person`, I get the following excpetion:

> Message:
>
> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a
>   store-generated column. Column: 'MainPersonSiteId'. Stack trace:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildSetClauses(DbExpressionBinding
>   target, PropagatorResult row, PropagatorResult originalRow,
>   TableChangeProcessor processor, Boolean insertMode, Dictionary`2&
>   outputIdentifiers, DbExpression& returning, Boolean& rowMustBeTouched)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildUpdateCommand(PropagatorResult
>   oldRow, PropagatorResult newRow, TableChangeProcessor processor) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.CompileCommands(ChangeNode
>   changeNode, UpdateCompiler compiler)

In the database, which is Sql Server 12, Person comes from a view, where MainPersonSiteId is projected from a function. This is a computed field, which does not need to be updated by the ORM.

How to define it with EntityFramework ?

**EDIT :**

I just managed to have update working by setting `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` instead of `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`, nevertheless I just found the inserts were still broken. So I tested the inserts with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` back and it ... worked :/

The situation is :
 - I can insert only with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed
 - I can update only with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity

It's strange as [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` let the DB generate a value for both inserts and updates while `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` does only for inserts

Comment: Can you do that in the database? Can you create a foreing key from a computed column? If you cannot do it in the database, I doubt you can do it with EF. If you can do it, please, show how.

Comment: @JotaBe, thanks for commenting. I think DatabaseGeneratedOption only says that the property is handled in some way by the DB. Quoted from MSDN, DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed means :  "The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated." Nothing more. EntityFramework should not touch this field.

Comment: EF will definitely touch that field to handle the FK. And I think you cannot create that FK in the database. Can you? How do you expect EF to do somethign that can't be done?

Answer (score 1):

Columns in the database defined as IDENTITY are different from COMPUTED ones.

When you insert a new row, then the database engine creates a new value (number) for an IDENTITY-Column. For example you can use this as a primary/unique key column. You can not update an IDENTITY column. You can't define a formula for doing calculations.

When you want to calculate somethin' at the table level, you can use computed columns. Here you have to define a formula. When you create the computed column with the PERSISTED option, then SQL-Server stores the computed values in the table. When you update columns which are part of a computed column, only then the computed column gets updated. PERSISTED computed columns can be part of index-key-columns and foreign keys. 
When you don't use the PERSISTED option, the database does not store the computed values. So it has to do the calculation every time a query needs the computed column.

When you update a row, make sure the computed column is not part of list of columns to be updated (in the SET-clause of an UPDATE-statement).

You can define FOREIGN KEYs only between tables and not views.